# Release build issues in converting json to list

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json file in main/assets folder -

```
[
  {
    "topic": "Studies",
    "subMessage": "....",
    "people": [
      ....
    ]
  },
  {
    "topic": "....",
    "subMessage": "...",
    "people": []
  }
]
```

I use this method below to parse the json and return a custom list of mine -

```
final List<MyList> readJson() {
        try {
            InputStream raw = context.getAssets().open(context.getResources().getString(R.string.read_the_json)); 
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(raw, "UTF-8);
            return new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<MyList>>() {
            }.getType());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error : " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

For Release build, I have `minifyEnabled true`. But for debug build it is false.

What I found is if I set `minifyEnabled` to false in release build it works but I need proguard for release builds.

The problem is in Release build the method returns me `[][]`. But in debug build, the method returns me the values from JSON.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened because the proguard tool modified your class. You will need to stop proguard from obfuscating the model classes.

**Not so good** but easiest way:

- Make all your model classes such as `MyList` implement the interface `Serializable`.
- Then in the file `proguard-rules.pro`, add the following line:

  `-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable { *; }`

**Better Way:**

- Directly include your model class in the file `proguard-rules.pro` file. For eg.

  `-keepclassmembers class com.example.MyList { *; }`

Comment: MyList implements Parcelable

Comment: Is implementing Serializable necessary? The OP should be able to write a `keepclassmembers` rule without that. And how will this help preserve the JSON file which is external to the class?

Comment: @Julia You can use any interface (`android.os.Parcelable` in your case) in proguard. Also you can implement multiple interfaces for a same class.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No it is not necessary. It is just one of the multiple ways.

Comment: Works...Instead of Serializable, I used -keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable { *; }

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Why not just name the class explicitly in your proguard rule? Keeping the rule narrowly focused seems best to me until you actually have a reason to make a rule for all classes that implement a particular interface.